# Some array indexes not being assigned correctly

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code, intended to reformat some strings in a CSV file:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => &$row) {
    print $key;
    print "\n";
    if ($row === count($rows) - 1) {
        break;
    }
    $columns = explode(";", $row);
    $columns[30] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[6]);  // ItemTypeTxt
    $columns[29] = "Sandberg";  // BrandTxt
    $columns[19] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[3]);  // Width
    $columns[18] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[4]);  // Height
    $columns[16] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[2]);  // Weight
    $columns[15] = "SDG";  // Brand
    $columns[12] = "SEK";  // Currency
    $columns[13] = round(floatval($columns[5]) * 0.2, 2);  // Price
    $columns[11] = round(floatval($columns[5]) * 0.8, 2);  // Price
    $columns[10] = round(floatval($columns[5]) * 0.8, 2);  // Price
    $columns[4] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[1]);  // Item
    $columns[2] = str_replace('"', '', $columns[0]);  // ItemOEM
    $columns[1] = "1";
    $columns[0] = "SDG" . str_replace('"', '', $columns[0]);  // ItemID
    $columns[32] = "-";
    $columns[31] = "-";
    $columns[28] = "-";
    $columns[27] = "-";
    $columns[26] = "-";
    $columns[25] = "-";
    $columns[24] = "-";
    $columns[23] = "-";
    $columns[22] = "-";
    $columns[21] = "-";
    $columns[20] = "-";
    $columns[17] = "-";
    $columns[14] = "-";
    $columns[9] = "-";
    $columns[8] = "-";
    $columns[7] = "-";
    $columns[6] = "-";
    $columns[5] = "-";
    $columns[3] = "-"; // Unknown values
        // Puts together the row into a string
    $row = implode(";", $columns);
    print $row;
}
```

Print is just for quick reference when fixing it up, the rows array are imploded into a $current variable after the for loop and further handled correctly.
One example this produces is:

```
SDG125-62;1;125-62;-;Sandberg Speak’n Go In-Earset Black;-;-;Hörlurar;Sandberg;1.1;2.5;19;SDG;SEK;0;0;0;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-
```

The first 4 elements are correct, but then it becomes wrong.
All elements from [3] to [9] should be empty, and only contain a minus sign (just for easier counting when endlessly staring as CSV files, the final product will be an empty string).
But as you can see in the example result, index 4 contains the value that should have gotten into index 10.

I am really new to PHP, so there might be some passing by reference quirk or similar thing i am not familiar with.

Comment: PHP assigns array indexes as given when input manually. If your array looks like `$arr[1] $arr[3] $arr[2]` then that's what it'll implode: `$arr[1] . ';' . $arr[3] . ';' $arr[2]`. It'll just go from 1 to 3 to 2 and not from 1 to 2 to 3. Hence you'll get unexpected results. Just `var_dump($array)` and you'll see for yourself

Comment: Aaah, so the assumed indexes really don't work as indexes, but becomes keys ordered into the assignment order?

How would i fix that and treat it as normal indexes?

Comment: You'll want to use [ksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) for that. It'll sort your array by the indexes. So just `ksort($array)`. No need to assign it. It'll sort the existing array

Comment: This is strange.
When i run var_dump, the ksort seems to work perfectly. But the final result is unaffected.

I put the ksort before implode(), and the var_dump after.

Comment: Nevermind, i was clumsy and didn't look properly.
It worked perfectly.
Thanks!

Comment: Sure no problem :) Glad you got it solved!